# Error destroying Backbone Relational model generated with Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, backbone-relational

I have a situation which has to be simple to solve, I would guess. Surely people are using Backbone Relational with CoffeeScript out there...

Here's a model I have:

```
class MyCompany.Models.Establishment extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  defaults:
    name: null

class MyCompany.Collections.EstablishmentsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: MyCompany.Models.Establishment
  url: '/establishments'
```

I haven't even added any relationships yet, just extended RelationalModel. Now through the console when I issue a destroy on an instance of the model it successfully destroys the model on the server, but when complete it fails with the trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Establishment> has no method 'getCollection'
    _.extend.unregister
    Backbone.Events.trigger
    Backbone.RelationalModel.Backbone.Model.extend.trigger
    _.extend.destroy.options.success
    jQuery.extend._Deferred.deferred.resolveWith
    done
    jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

It's dying in line 235 of backbone-relational.js 0.4.0 because "this" is the model, I guess, instead of whatever it's supposed to be, and the model doesn't have a method "getCollection".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or should I report a bug? For reference, here's the Javascript  coffee generates:

```
(function() {
  var __hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, __extends = function(child, parent) {
    for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; }
    function ctor() { this.constructor = child; }
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new ctor;
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child;
  };
  MyCompany.Models.Establishment = (function() {
    __extends(Establishment, Backbone.RelationalModel);
    function Establishment() {
      Establishment.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Establishment.prototype.defaults = {
      name: null
    };
    return Establishment;
  })();
  MyCompany.Collections.EstablishmentsCollection = (function() {
    __extends(EstablishmentsCollection, Backbone.Collection);
    function EstablishmentsCollection() {
      EstablishmentsCollection.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    EstablishmentsCollection.prototype.model = MyCompany.Models.Establishment;
    EstablishmentsCollection.prototype.url = '/establishments';
    return EstablishmentsCollection;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

Comment: What command are you using to destroy the model from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the underlying Backbone.js version. Here's why:

Your error comes from `this` having the wrong value when `unregister` is called. `unregister` is called in response to an event bound from `register`:

```
model.bind( 'destroy', this.unregister, this );
```

That third argument sets the context. But that feature was only added as recently as Backbone 0.5.2, as the [changelog](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#changelog) shows.

Comment: Working on this. I've just upgraded to 0.5.3, but it still seems to be happening. I'm trying to track down and make sure everything is set up right.

Comment: I needed to clear the Rails caches and restart pow. I was getting served something old somewhere. Seems to be working now. Thanks for tracking that down for me Trevor.